# How to fix character encoding issue in html?

Tags: html, encoding, utf-8, notepad++

I have a web page, and if I open it in windows notepad, a piece of text looks like this

`Avertissement sur la sécurité`

But if I open it in notepad++, it looks like

[image]

Notepad++ also says the file is in utf-8 encoding too.

If I open it in a browser, it looks like

[image]

I have

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">` on top too.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you save the file in `UTF-8 without BOM` and see if that works? See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2223926/6022243

Comment: Make the webpage english instead of french ;D

Answer (score 6):

You have to make sure the encoding on `<meta>` is the same like the file encoding (on Notepad++).

**You want to use UTF-8?**

- On Notepad++ select `Encoding -> UTF-8 (without BOM)` and save the file.
- Use `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`

**You want to use ISO-8859-15?**

- On Notepad++ select `Encoding -> ISO-8859-15` and save the file.
- Use `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-15">`